# NameError uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations, simple-form

In trying to render a form im getting:

```
NameError in Deals#new

Showing /Users/nelsonkeating/Desktop/ReminDeal1/app/views/deals/_form.html.erb where line #8 raised:

uninitialized constant Deal::Interests
Extracted source (around line #8):

5:  <li><%= f.input :name %></li>
6:  <li><%= f.input :copy %></li>
7:  <li><%= f.association :city %></li>
8:   <li><%= f.association :interests, :label => false, :as => :check_boxes %></li>
9:  </ul>
10: 
11:   <div class="form-actions">
```

The relevant parts of the app are attached below:

Models:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :title, :body
   belongs_to :interests
   belongs_to :city
end

class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :person_interests
  has_many :deals
end
```

Controller:

```
deals_controller.rb
  def new
    @deal = Deal.new
end
```

View:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@deal) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
<ul class="testss1">

    <li><%= f.input :name %></li>
    <li><%= f.input :copy %></li>
    <li><%= f.association :city %></li>
    <li><%= f.association :interests, :label => false, :as => :check_boxes %></li>
 </ul>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas? Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `belongs_to :interest`.

If you need multiple interests it's likely you want a `has_many:through`.